# collectionView inside view controller not showing

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add a collectionView inside a view controller. In the view controller i already have some content and I'm trying to add a collection view as a subview right below the last content in the view controller. I'm not sure how else to go about it. Please help. Here's the code below:

```
import UIKit

class StoreDetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureUI()
}

func configureUI() {

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    navigationItem.title = "Store"

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named: "store")
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return image
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let name = UILabel()
        name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .heavy)
        name.text = names
        name.numberOfLines = 2
        name.textColor = .primaryDark
        return name
    }()

    let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
        let description = UILabel()
        description.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
        description.text = desc
        description.numberOfLines = 5
        description.textColor = .primaryDark
        return description
    }()

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translateAll()
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.register(StoreProductsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        cv.backgroundColor = .red
        return cv
    }()

    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.addSubview(nameLabel)
    view.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! StoreProductsCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    return cell
}
```

}

I also added the constraints already but i didn't include it in the code. the other details in the vc shows fine but it's just the collection view that's not registering inside the view controller

Comment: Did you try to change  "frame: .zero" to some value?

Comment: no it's .zero i didn't change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `collectionView.reloadData()` after adding it to your view.